# Manipulate elements with radio button change - jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I wrote the following script but I can't find out why it doesn't work properly. 
The idea is when you check a radio button to get it's value which is equal to the name of a class. After that to hide() the current window and to show the element with the class name equal to the radio button value:

```js
var userChoice;
var currentQuest;

 $(document).ready(function() {

     $('input[type=radio][name=question]').change(function() {

      userChoice = $('input[name=question]:checked').val();
      currentQuest = $('.container-quest').attr('id');

      $(currentQuest).hide();
      $(userChoice).show(500);
     });
 });
```

```css
#b1-l11-q3,
#b1-l11-q4 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="b1-l10-q2" class="container-quest">
  <div class="step-container">
    <p>
      Choose one of these!
    </p>
    <form>
      <input type="radio" name="question" value="b1-l11-q3">Div - 1<br />
      <input type="radio" name="question" value="b1-l11-q4">Div - 2
    </form>
  </div>
</div><!-- end -->

<div id="b1-l11-q3"> Div 1 </div>
<div id="b1-l11-q4"> Div 2 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type=radio]').change(function() {
   $('.choice').hide();
        userChoice = $(this).val();
    console.log(userChoice)


        $('#'+userChoice).show(500);
    });
});
```

Example here:

https://jsfiddle.net/5qne0skd/2/

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thank you Franco! Great answer!

Answer (score 1):

you need to add `#`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[type=radio][name=question]').change(function() {

            userChoice = $('input[name=question]:checked').val();
            currentQuest = $('.container-quest').attr('id');
            $('#'+currentQuest).hide(); // <<<<<<<<  add # 
            $('#'+userChoice).show(500); // <<<<<<<< add #
        });
    });
```

[**Simple Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/320yqj4a/) to explain the defference between use `#` and wihout use `#`

As  @DinoMyte mentioned in comment .. so you can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
     $('input[type=radio][name=question]').change(function() {
        userChoice = $(this).val();
        currentQuest = $(this).closest('.container-quest');
        currentQuest.hide();
        $('#'+userChoice).show(500); // <<<<<<<< add #
     });
});
```

Comment: Mohamed, why is that? Isn't that selection refers to id selection?

Comment: @RoniAxelrad no if you try to print $('anyselector').attr('id'); it will return just a string text

Comment: @RoniAxelrad you can check it here https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/320yqj4a/

Comment: Yeah you're right, I didn't get his complete idea in the beginning, thanks Mohammed, nice solution!

Comment: userChoice = $('input[name=question]:checked').val(); can simply be replaced with userChoice =  $(this).val();

Comment: @DinoMyte totally right .. and he can not get the id of the parent to hide it .. he just need to use .closest() .. Thanks :)